# "put down" ≠ make a down payment?

Tags: meaning, expressions, vocabulary

> A Peace Corps volunteer started a credit union requiring people receiving a new home to **put down** community references in lieu of collateral. These references were friends, family members, or neighbors who could vouch that the applicants would pay the loan. The decision to create these arrangement was based on microfinance – the idea that people would be more likely to default on their own possessions than to compromise their reputation in the community and let their community down […]"

I'm quite confused as to the meaning of "put down" on this sentence. I thought it could mean "down payment", but you can't put down a person…

And collateral is something the person owns that serves as a guarantee, but if it's part of the a down payment, it's no longer a guarantee.

So I don't think put down really means make a down payment. Could somebody please explain how this system works and what "put down" means in this sentence?

Comment: It is likely referring to _to pay part of the cost of something and agree to pay the rest later_ where instead you put a list of referrals down (on the table)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Put down* does have a meaning *write down* which could easily extend to *nominate* or *register* in this case. See definition 29 at [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/put+down?r=66):

> 29. **put down**
>   a. to write down; register; record.
>   b. to enter in a list, as of subscribers or contributors: *Put me down for a $10 donation.*

What you don't want is another standard sense — which **could** be applied to humans, I suppose:

> k. to put (an animal) to death; put away.

Comment: but with "put down" it means to register community members as a guarantee?

Comment: I would certainly take it to mean "write down to register them".

Comment: It is very likely a play on words. Make a downpayment OR make a list of referrals.

Comment: I agree with @mplungjan. Normally, you would *put down* a deposit of money - here you are *putting down* (depositing) a reference.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is using "put down community references" and not "put community references down"? I think those are identical and it means *write down* or *register* as senses (a) and (b) for ***put down*** which I quoted.

Comment: ‘To put down references’ is quite an idiomatic expression that simply means ‘to list references’ on some kind of CV/application form/contract/what-have-you.

In this case, the meaning is quite clear: instead of putting down a deposit or making a downpayment, you simply submit references from others in the community who have vouched for you.